# SDIC of tent map like structure

Tags: dynamical-systems

a tent map like structure is defined as T(x)=3/2x if x is in [0,1/2) and T(x)=3/2(1-x) if x is in [1/2,3/4]. How can I show that T has sensitive dependence on initial conditions?